# Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Object'. Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to subscribe to an async function in Angular. VSCode marks `subscribe` as deprecated & `res['user']` marks: `Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Object'`.

```js
getUser(){
  this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.user = res['user'];
    },
    err => { 
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

```js
getUserProfile() {
  return this.http.get(this.url + '/userProfile');
}
```

Comment: You should _use_ TypeScript. Read e.g. https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response

Answer (score 0):

`subscribe` itself isn't deprecated, only the variant you are using is deprecated. You'd rather write your code as follows:

```
getUser(){
    this.getUserProfile().subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
            this.user = res.user;
        },
        error: (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```